# 'SaveUser(string)' :Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please Help! This is the last error I'm getting that I need to fix."SaveUser" is getting the error 'clsDataLayer.SaveUser(string, string, string, string)':not all code paths return a value

```
// This function saves the user login
    public static bool SaveUser(string Database, string UserName, string UserPassword, string SecurityLevel)
    {
        bool recordSaved;

        try
        {
            // Add your comments here
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Database);

            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            string strSQL;

            strSQL = "Insert into tblUserLogin (UserName, UserPassword, SecurityLevel) values ('" +
            UserName + "', '" + UserPassword + "', '" + SecurityLevel + "')";

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = strSQL;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
            recordSaved = true;



        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

}
```

Here is the if else for this process

```
protected void btnAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clsDataLayer.SaveUser(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.accdb"),
UserName.Text, UserPassword.Text, ddlSecurityLevel.SelectedValue))
        {

            lblDisplay.Text = "The user was successfully added!";
            grdUsers.DataBind();
        }

        else
            lblDisplay.Text = "The user was not added!";


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything. Instead of

```
recordSaved = true;
```

you can just do:

```
return true;
```

Also as you're catching exceptions, you'll need to return something from the catch block too e.g.

```
catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
```